# Error in listing packages in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When I click "Refresh Pakcage Listing", I got "Error listing packages" in RStudio.

[image]

In the mean time, the commandline shows `Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string 1`.
[image]

Could anybody help me fix this error?

RStudio verstion: Version 0.98.1062
OS: Win 7, 64bit

Comment: I think support.rstudio.org would be a better hub for this.

Comment: try re-install R and RStudio in a pure ASCII path. 试试把R和RStudio装在纯英文的路径里。

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because of the name of my windows account. I used multi-byte account name which was Korean, so the R studio seems to have problem recognizing the folder. So I changed the name of my user folder name to an English name, using alphabets only and fixed my problem. Please refer to [the following link](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/28/how-to-change-a-windows-account-name-and-user-profile-folder-name/) to change the user folder name. Hope this helps. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by running the following line in the **RStudio** Console, but don't know why it does:

```
  Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "us")
```